# Expalanation for the equality $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Why is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$$

in

$$ 4\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2k-1}=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=4\arctan(1)=\pi$$

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: Shift the index by letting $k=j+1$ :
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_{j+1}$ and note that $(-1)^{j+2}=(-1)^j$.

Comment: This problem has **totally changed** in the edit. Anyway, both sides are $$\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the left sum with $k = i+1$. Thus $LHS = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{[(i+1)+1]}}{2(i+1)-1}= \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^i}{2i+1} = RHS$ . (FYI: didn't look at hint or comments ...while doing this...)